# Delphi. Multidimensional array as argument

Tags: arrays, delphi, multidimensional-array

I have multidimensional array:
`TBMArray = TArray<array of byte>;`
And recursive function
`function goForSolve(bData: TBMArray; const iSize: integer): TBMArray;`

At this function i have
`tempData: TBMArray;`
I need to change tempData without changing the value of bData. But when i change tempData, bData also changes. I tried to copy bData to tempData by function

```
procedure copyData(Source: TBMArray; var Dest: TBMArray);  
var  
  iCurEl, iLen: integer;  
begin  
  iLen := length(Source);  
  setLength(Dest, iLen);  
  setLength(Dest[0], 1);  
  for iCurEl := 1 to iLen - 1 do  
    setLength(Dest[iCurEl], iCurEl + 1);  
  for iCurEl := Low(Source) to High(Source) do  
    Dest[iCurEl] := Source[iCurEl];  
end;
```

But result is the same as

```
tempData := bData;
```

It seems like function copy pointers instead of values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A dynamic array is a reference type. Behind the scenes they are implemented as pointers to the data structure. When you assign a dynamic array variable you are simply taking another reference to the existing dynamic array object. So, that explains the behaviour you observe.

There is a function that can be used to make a copy of a dynamic array, the aptly named [`Copy`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Copy). So you could write:

```
Dest := Copy(Source);
```

This would make a copy of the outer array, but not the inner arrays. So instead you will need to iterate over the outer arrays yourself, and call `Copy` to make new copies of the inner arrays. Perhaps like this:

```
type
  TBMArray = TArray<TArray<Byte>>;

function CopyBMArray(const src: TBMArray): TBMArray;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(src));
  for i := 0 to high(Result) do begin
    Result[i] := Copy(src[i]);
  end;
end;
```

Note that I have tweaked the definition of `TBMArray`. I urge you to do the same since it will greatly ease your development. Generic types have much more relaxed type compatibility rules and using `TArray<T>` wherever possible will lead to much more composable code.

Comment: Great answer. And now I need to add "deep copy" to my very, very long Delphi wishlist....